# How to localize an accessibility label

Tags: ios, localization, accessibility

I'm researching accessibility features in iOS. I can't seem to find how you localise the label for different locales.

If I enter labels directly into the nib in interface builder, can I only localise these by localising the WHOLE nib? Or is there a way to get these exported to a string file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is that the WHOLE nib (or xib, actually) is meant to be localized per language.  There's one xib for English, one for Spanish, one for Japanese, etc.

Comment: There, I accepted your answer! I trust you're happy. It's a shame that this is the only way - it would be nice to have a solution to send this through a text file which could then be translated. Localising a whole nib seems excessive.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it programmatically, no need for multiple nibs:

```
@implementation MyCustomViewController
- (id)init
{
  _view = [[[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
  [_view setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];

  [_view setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitButton];
  [_view setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"view.label", nil)];
  [_view setAccessibilityHint:NSLocalizedString(@"view.hint", nil)];
}
```

Taken from the [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5)

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though programmatically setting the accessibility labels could be accomplished in the same manner as setting any other UI component in a xib, using IBOutlets.

Best practices / techniques for localization is another topic entirely, but we generally avoid  localizing the xib when possible (eg. ensuring that designs have enough space to handle the differences among the languages we support, avoiding text in images, etc.), relying on NSLocalizedString to adjust user-facing (and/or user-audible?) copy.